# Brows OpenERP contacts using java code

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I have a problem running the following java code for browsing contacts from openERP 
the first part run with out problem , the login part done , but I got exception on the line

```
Object c = client.execute("execute", arg);
```

it says there is a problem in casting...

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;

public class Browse {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
// USEFUL ONLY LOCALLY WITH IN THE SERVER
Vector params1 = new Vector();
params1.addElement("TS_DB");
params1.addElement("alaa");
params1.addElement("123456");

XmlRpcClient xmlrpcLogin = new XmlRpcClient();
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl xmlrpcConfigLogin = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
xmlrpcConfigLogin.setEnabledForExtensions(true);
xmlrpcConfigLogin.setServerURL(new URL("http", "10.0.0.177", 8069, "/xmlrpc/common"));
xmlrpcLogin.setConfig(xmlrpcConfigLogin);

Object id = xmlrpcLogin.execute("login", params1);
System.out.println("Login Id : " + id.toString());

System.out.println("------------------------");

XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl clientConfig = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
clientConfig.setEnabledForExtensions(true);
clientConfig.setServerURL(new URL("http", "10.0.0.177", 8069, "/xmlrpc/object"));
client.setConfig(clientConfig);

// Object[] params2 = { "parner_id", "name" };
Object[] params2 = { 11 };
Vector<Object> params = new Vector<Object>();
params.add(params2);
Vector<Object> arg = new Vector<Object>();
arg.add("TS_DB");
arg.add(1);
arg.add("alaa");
arg.add("res.partner.address");
arg.add("browse");
// arg.add(24);
arg.add(params2);

Object c = client.execute("execute", arg);
// System.out.println("partner addressees with partner Id 24 :");
// for (Object obj : ids) {
// int a = Integer.parseInt(obj.toString());
// System.out.println(a);
// }

}
}
```

I got the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.XmlRpcResponseParser.addResult(XmlRpcResponseParser.java:61)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.RecursiveTypeParserImpl.endValueTag(RecursiveTypeParserImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.XmlRpcResponseParser.endElement(XmlRpcResponseParser.java:186)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2939)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:186)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
    at Browse.main(Browse.java:47)
```

Comment: Hello, You can not user browse Method out side the server enviroment, you have to use `read` method. So please use read method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the user id to the arg vector. The user id which you has got by logging into the database has to be provided to the arg vector in order to call the particular method.
But yeah it has to show some other exception other than that cast exception but I don't know why that error comes. But the solution is simple just replace the statement:

```
arg.add(1);
```

With this one:

```
arg.add(id);
```

The `id` above was set as follows:

```
Object id = xmlrpcLogin.execute("login", params1);
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know xmlrpc is not able to return object which browse method of openerp return .
so you have to use read method for the same.

Comment: I got the same exception for the read method    Object[] params2 = { "city", "name", "partner_id", "country_id", "email", "create_date",
  "write_date" };

  Vector<Object> arg = new Vector<Object>();

  arg.add("openerpdb");
  arg.add(1);
  arg.add("admin");
  arg.add("res.partner.address");
  arg.add("read");
  arg.add(3);
  arg.add(params2);
HashMap ids = (HashMap) client.execute("execute", arg);

Comment: this error is coming at time ro reading response or when sending request.